# TempFile Java program not working on linux

Tags: java, linux, unix, buffer

I have a program which creates a tempFile and write data inside of it.

The program works on windows but not on Linux, could someone tell me why ?

This is intended to be a script executed with input file(s) as parameter.

This is what I do in my code :

```
if (args.length > 0){
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            fileList.add(new File(args[i]));
            renameFile(fileList.get(i));
        }


public static void renameFile(File fileOriginal) throws IOException{
    File destination = new File(fileOriginal + "");
    try {


        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("buffer", ".tmp");
        System.out.println("File path: "+tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);
        Reader fr = new FileReader(fileOriginal);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);



        while (br.ready()) {
            fw.write(br.readLine().replace("#/A#" , "Á").  
                    replace("#/a#" , "á").  
                    replace("#:A#" , "Ä").  
                    replace("#:a#" , "ä").  
                    replace("#>C#" , "Č").  
                    replace("#>c#" , "č").  
                    replace("#>D#" , "Ď").  
                    replace("#d'#" , "ď").  
                    replace("#/I#" , "Í").  
                    replace("#/i#" , "í").  
                    replace("#L'#" , "Ľ").  
                    replace("#l'#" , "ľ").  
                    replace("#>N#" , "Ň").  
                    replace("#>n#" , "ň").  
                    replace("#/O#" , "Ó").  
                    replace("#/o#" , "ó").  
                    replace("#>r#" , "ř").  
                    replace("#/r#" , "ŕ").  
                    replace("#/R#" , "Ŕ").  
                    replace("#>S#" , "Š").  
                    replace("#>s#" , "š").  
                    replace("#/t#" , "ť").  
                    replace("#>T#" , "Ť").  
                    replace("#/U#" , "Ú").  //
                    replace("#/u#" , "ú").  
                    replace("#/Y#" , "Ý").  
                    replace("#/y#" , "ý").  
                    replace("#/Z#" , "Ź").  
                    replace("#/z#" , "ź").  
                    replace("#>Z#" , "Ž").  
                    replace("#>z#" , "ž").  
                    replace("#>E#" , "Ě").  
                    replace("#>e#" , "ě").  
                    replace("#>R#" , "Ř").  
                    replace("#oU#" , "Ů").  
                    replace("#ou#" , "ů")); 

        }

        fw.close();
        br.close();
        fr.close();

        //Rename original file in a .backup
        File originalFileRenamed = new File(fileOriginal + ".backup");
        if(fileOriginal.renameTo(originalFileRenamed))
            System.out.println("");
        else
            System.out.println("Original file already exist, cannot rename it, please delete it");


        //Rename the temp file I was working on.
        tempFile.renameTo(destination); 


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Sorry for putting such a long code but I can't find where to problem comes from.

The problem is the fact that the output file does not appear on Linux but does on Windows.
Program executes itself but doesn't give an output file.

In short, i'm just writing inside a file using tempFile, buffer and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Do you receive any errors? Do you use a try-catch block to catch possible errors? Can you verify, that the program has permission to create a file, or are there any IOErrors stating this or similar issues?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work because `fileOriginal` does not exists on the Linux mache or is empty?

Comment: Try calling the method `File.createTempFile` which takes 3 parameters and provide the directory as well. More info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)

Comment: You should provide a working code snippet. So it would be easier to understand what all you do. What have you done to find the source of the unexpected bahviour? What is the result of `tempFile.renameTo(destination)` (it returns a `booelan` value)? Maybe the rename is not working, e.g. because of (from [File javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-)) `The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another,...`

Comment: I put almost the whole code in the subject for you to see a bit more.

Comment: Still the question. What is the result of `tempFile.renameTo(destination);`. In your code you simply ignore the returned value. Another question: To which location points `tempFile.getAbsolutePath()`?

Comment: This is the return from getAbsolutePath() in Windows : C:\Users\A673181\AppData\Local\Temp\buffer2928032837388126822.tm

Comment: This is the return from getAbsolutePath() in Windows : C:\Users\A673181\AppData\Local\Temp\buffer2928032837388126822.tmp

And this is when I run it on linux : /tmp/buffer4419171625487249156.tmp.


tempFile.renameTo(destination) is used to rename the file in input so I have 2 output files (1 which is modified by the program and 1 which is lefet untouched(but renamed).

Comment: I have all privilege in all linux folders in question btw